# ASP.NET Core - RESTful API - Request Validation - Minimize Database Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have the following DTO class

```
public class CustomerDTO {   
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public string CustomerType { get; set; }

   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

   public bool IsPremierCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

I have a POST method that accepts this DTO. I need to perform a database lookup to make sure 'CustomerType' contains a valid value (it must be one of the pre-defined values stored in database). Once the lookup is successful, I also need to get the 'Id' corresponding to the 'CustomerType' so that I can create the record successfully (the DTO is mapped to my internal entity class which requires the 'Id').

I am using 'FluentValidations' for validations and 'AutoMapper' for mapping between types. The POST method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<CustomerDTO> Create([FromBody] CustomerDTO customer) {
   var customerType = _customerTypeRepository.FindByDescription(customer.CustomerType);

   if (customerType == null) {
      ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(customer.CustomerType), "'Customer Type' is not a valid type.");
      return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
   }

   var newCustomer = _mapper.Map<CustomerEntity>(customer);
   newCustomer.CustomerTypeId = customerType.Id;

   var createdCustomer = _customerRepository.Create(newCustomer);
   var dto = _mapper.Map<CustomerDTO>(createdCustomer);

   return CreatedAtRoute("GetCustomer", new { customerId = dto.Id }, dto);
}
```

I cannot define this validation rule as part of 'FluentValidation' profile since it would result in multiple calls to the database - one for the validation itself and then another one for getting the 'Id'.

Is there a better approach to do this - I want to avoid unnecessary calls to the database.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If the customer type is 'static' - meaning that there will be no new values added to the database during the lifetime of your application, you can just query the database once (configure that in Startup) and cache the response.

Then in your validator, and anywhere else you can refer to that cache for Customer type/id

Comment: yes, caching can definitely be done and it will definitely improve performance. Thanks.

Comment: You probably could use CustomAsync() method of fluentvalidations library where you could place you database query which will check both type and id in one query